# Speed of enumerating Hashset

Tags: c#, performance, hashset

Is there any performance difference between these two enumerations of a `Hashset<string>` in C#?

```
foreach(string value1 in Hashset1) {

}
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < Hashset1.Count; i++) {
    string _value1 = Hashset1.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Is there any other fast enumeration (performance wise) of a `Hashset`?

Comment: You should try and avoid enumerating hash-sets & dictionaries wherever possible.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Do some benchmarks and draw your conclusions, it's not hard to do.

Comment: Here is a link that explains how to answer this kind of questions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/02/20/535807.aspx

Comment: @DaveBish Could you explain why?

Comment: @svick - The way hash-sets are implemented - means that there will always be "buckets" that are empty see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table - meaning that any enumeration will always have to hit & skip-over empty memory locations.

Comment: @DaveBish The way `HashSet` and `Dictionary` are implemented in .Net is that each non-empty bucket points to an linked list. And all linked lists are stored in a single array. You can iterate that array easily, without any skipping. (There actually may be some skipping, if you remove entries from the hash.) So, I think your advice is unfounded.

Comment: @svick cheers - I learned something! That must mean adding items incurs the cost of adding to the array, or something, internally?

Comment: @DaveBish It uses the same strategy as `List<T>`: when the array becomes full, its size doubles. This means that worst-case, adding an item is O(n), but the amortized cost of adding is still O(1), because the array resizing happens only rarely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it matters, you should benchmark and see for yourself what is the faster solution in your scenario.

In this case the second solution is pretty much guaranteed to be slower because ElementAt is an Enumerable extension method. It has an optimized path for IList<T>, which HashSet<T> does not implement. So it takes the "normal" path which is enumerating N elements from your IEnumerable<T>.

You can figure out for yourself that your second solution has O(N^2) complexity, while the first is surely O(N).

Is there any other fast enumeration of HashSet? No, I don't think so. That's what IEnumerable is for. But isn't this fast enough for you? Micro-benchmarking is useless and I would worry if your performance was bound by this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a huge difference between the two.

`Enumerable.ElementAt(int)` is an O(n) operation, so your second is has O(n^2) complexity.

In contrast, enumerating the set through the enumerator is an O(n) operation.