# Hiding a column in the dataGridView, then displaying all columns again

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

My dataGridView contains multiple columns.  I can hide individual columns, but then I want the ability to show all columns again.  I can do this with a for statement; however, I thought I should be able to do it with a foreach as well; however, I cannot get the syntax right.

My working for statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = true;
}
```

What I tried in the foreach statement:

```
foreach (var column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[column].Visible = true;
}
```

I understand that I need the index value for the column; however, I'm missing how to get it from the column value.  What's really driving me crazy is that I know its something simple that I'm missing!

On a side note, is it better to use a for or foreach for this?  Or is there really any benefit of one over the other?

Thank you for your help.
Brian.

Comment: I don't sure but..did you try to use columne.ColumnIndex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    column.Visible = true;
}
```

With the `foreach`, you can act directly on the object. In this case, the only benefit is readability really, although it also removes the need for an extra `int` variable. In general, `foreach` can be more efficient, because it leaves the implementation up to the individual collection class, which of course knows the most efficient way to enumerate itself. Example: [`HashSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180316/speed-of-enumerating-hashset)

Note that because the `Columns` property is a `DataGridViewColumnCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<DataGridViewColumn>` or similar, you must specify the type of your variable. If you say `var`, you will get `object`.

I believe this is because `DataGridView` was designed before generics were implemented.

Comment: Simple indeed.  Thank you Blorgbeard!  It works like a charm.